# How to check user email before submitting payment with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like to create a payment form via Stripe that takes the user's email address and payment information. This information then gets sent to my server via Flask, and if the user's email address meets a specific criteria set by me, then I process the payment. Otherwise, I cancel the payment.

From my research, I have found two approaches that seem to be viable. Although I haven't been able to form a complete solution in either.

The first method is to follow this guide https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time and modify it slightly. When the user clicks my "BUY NOW" button, I POST to the following API:

```
@app.route("/generate_session", methods=["POST"])
def generate_session():
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'name': 'T-shirt',
            'description': 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt',
            'images': ['https://example.com/t-shirt.png'],
            'amount': 500,
            'currency': 'gbp',
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
        payment_intent_data={
            'capture_method': 'manual',
        },
        success_url='http://localhost:5000/success',
        cancel_url='http://localhost:5000/cancel',
    )
    return session["id"]
```

I then execute the stripe `redirectCheckout` function with this session id:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_lp7ZS0B23jNmorIoW6Wj0Rs2009E1xTCwS');
sessionId = "" // send POST and get response
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  sessionId: sessionId
}).then(function (result) {
});
```

Since I have defined the `'capture_method'` to be `'manual'`, doing this will not actually submit the payment. What I need to do, is POST to /api/process_payment with the session_id once the user clicks Pay. This is the bit I am struggling with.

```
@app.route("/api/process_payment", methods=["POST])
def process_payment():
    data = request.get_json()
    session_id = data["session_id"]
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(session_id)
    payment_intent = session["payment_intent"]
    if session["customer_email"] == "abc@mail.com":  # will perform a different check, just a trivial example
        stripe.PaymentIntent.confirm(payment_intent,)
        # verify payment
        success = True
    else:
        stripe.PaymentIntent.cancel(payment_intent,)
        success = False
    return jsonify({"success": success})
```

Here are the docs I used to help with that part: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve, https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm, https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/cancel.

---

The second approach was to use [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) to make a form which takes the email and payment information. And since that already sends the information to my server before processing, it would be trivial to check the email before processing a payment. However, in my opinion Stripe Elements is an absolute mess and I'd like to avoid awful boilerplate code like it at all costs. I've tried to make a form that fits my specs but I haven't gotten close. I found this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/foc0L56q/ but it doesn't seem complete and changing the CSS seems like a huge pain.

Ideally, I would like help working out the first option, but if anyone can help me complete the second option then that would be great too.

Comment: Note that with your first approach (Checkout), you are actually authorizing that amount on the Customer's card. They'll see it on their bank's transactions page as a hold against their card.

The recommended approach is to use Elements, check the email address when it's posted to your backend, and then only create the Payment Intent if your checks all pass.

Comment: @taintedzodiac Are you sure? Can you link me to the documentation around that? I just can't use Elements it's so terrible.

Comment: @taintedzodiac https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create "Place a hold on the funds when the customer authorizes the payment, but don’t capture the funds until later. (Not all payment methods support this.)" seems you're right. Is that a problem though? It only won't go through if they're buying the wrong product or their payment is declined. And I cancel it anyway with `stripe.PaymentIntent.cancel(payment_intent,)`.

Comment: It's not a "problem" in and of itself, but it's not a best practice as you're actually creating the payment with the user's bank, and then later actually collecting the payment. If you use Elements and wait to create the PaymentIntent until after you verify the email address, you don't get banks involved and thus you're not creating "real" transactions until you're ready. I'd really recommend writing to https://support.stripe.com/email as they can answer more specifically about the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the first approach by setting the success_url to include the `session_id` as a parameter on a custom page. Then when that page loads, via Flask I take the session_id and retrieve the information as follows

```
data = request.args
session_id = data["session_id"]
session = stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(session_id)
payment_intent_id = session["payment_intent"]
payment_intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.retrieve(payment_intent_id,)
customer_email = payment_intent["charges"]["data"][0]["billing_details"]["email"]
if customer_email == "abc@mail.com":  # will perform a different check, just a trivial example
    stripe.PaymentIntent.capture(payment_intent_id, )
    # verify payment
    success = True
else:
    stripe.PaymentIntent.cancel(payment_intent_id, )
    success = False
return f"{success}"
```

**EDIT:** As mentioned, this places a hold on the funds so maybe not the best idea. Working on approach 2.